# How to insert a pre-initialized dataframe or several columns into another dataframe at a specified column position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose we have the following dataframe.

```
  col1 col2   col3
0  one  two  three
1  one  two  three
2  one  two  three
3  one  two  three
4  one  two  three
```

We seek to introduce 31 columns into this dataframe, each column representing a day in the month.

Let's say we want to introduce it precisely between columns `col2` and `col3`.

How do we achieve this?

To make it simple, the introduced columns can be numbered from 1 to 31.

**Starting source code**

```py
import pandas as pd

src = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','one'],    
                    'col2': ['two', 'two', 'two', 'two','two'],    
                    'col3': ['three', 'three', 'three', 'three','three'],
                    })
```

Comment: Do you really have 2 existing DataFrames? Or you want to add new columns in the middle with 0?

Comment: Both are ok then to aim the target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.concat([src.iloc[:, :2].assign(
    **{str(col): 0 for col in range(1, 32)}), src['col3']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ...  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  \
0  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
2  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
4  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

    col3  
0  three  
1  three  
2  three  
3  three  
4  three  

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and reorder columns with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) like the below:

```
import numpy as np

# Create dataframe with 31 column and 5 rows
tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 31)), columns=range(1, 32))

# Concat two dataframes and reorder columns as you like
df = pd.concat([src.iloc[:,:2], tmp, src.iloc[:, 2:]], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8  ...   23   24   25   26  \
0  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
2  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
3  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
4  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   

    27   28   29   30   31   col3  
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three  
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three  
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three  
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three  
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three  

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: `pd.concat([src.iloc[:,:2], tmp, src.iloc[:, 2:]], axis=1)` saves you the reordering.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign values to the original dataframe and reorder the columns using column selection.

```py
src[list(range(1, 32))] = 0
src = src[[*src.columns[:2], *range(1, 32), src.columns[2]]]
```

or for an entirely new copy, use `assign`:

```py
cols = list(map(str, range(1, 32)))
new_df = (
    src
    .assign(**dict.fromkeys(cols, 0))
    .reindex(columns=[*src.columns[:2], *cols, *src.columns[2:]])
)
```

[image: res]

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to add and initialize new columns, use `reindex`:

```
cols = list(src)
cols[2:2] = range(1,31+1)

df = src.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31   col3
0  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  three
1  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  three
2  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  three
3  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  three
4  one  two  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  three
```

Comment: I actually understand your concern. There are two ways to aim the target. considering the insertion of columns or considering the insertion of a dataframe. I viewed the dataframe like a bunch of columns but it may not be exactly right...

Answer (score 0):

**For illustrative purposes**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

src = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','one'],    
                    'col2': ['two', 'two', 'two', 'two','two'],    
                    'col3': ['three', 'three', 'three', 'three','three'],
                    })

m = np.matrix([0]*31) # Builds a 31-columns numpy array matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(m) # Converts matrix to dataframe
df.columns = df.columns+1 # Increments columns from 1 in dataframe

# Operations on dataframe : extension + resetting index + replace Nan by 0
df = (df.reindex(list(range(0, len(src))))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .fillna(0))

df = pd.concat([src.iloc[:, :2], df, src.iloc[:, 2:]], axis=1) # inserts by slicing source in two parts
```

**Result**

```
  col1 col2    1    2    3    4    5  ...   26   27   28   29   30   31   col3
0  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three
1  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three
2  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three
3  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three
4  one  two  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  three

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: This was my reply. I post it but I am looking for a better way to have the result